# Trying to show a checkbox when one of seven values in a form is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to show the #authorized_to_purchase_box if one of the seven job titles marked with data-auth="need-purchase-auth" is selected.

Not sure why it's not working. Please critique/let me know if there's a better way to do this.

HTML:

```
<select name="job_title" id="job_title" onchange='showAuthBox(this);'>
    <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
    <option id="Superintendent" value="Superintendent">Superintendent</option>
    <option id="Assistant-Superintendent" value="Assistant Superintendent">Assistant Superintendent</option>
    <option id="Principal" value="Principal">Principal</option>
    <option id="Vice-Principal" value="Vice Principal">Vice Principal</option>
    <option id="Counselor" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Counselor">Counselor</option>
    <option id="Testing-Coordinator" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Testing Coordinator">Testing Coordinator</option>
    <option id="Curriculum-Director" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Curriculum Director">Curriculum Director</option>
    <option id="Administrator" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
    <option id="Teacher" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
    <option id="Parent" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Parent">Parent</option>
    <option id="Student" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Student">Student</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
function showAuthBox(val) {
    alert(val.dataset.auth);
    if(val.dataset.auth == "need-purchase-auth") {
        $('#authorized_to_purchase_box').css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $('#authorized_to_purchase_box').css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

Comment: the `val` being passed to `showAuthBox` is the `select` element, not the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have modified the code a little bit to use jQuery's change event.

Here is the code:

```
$("#job_title").change(function() {
  var auth = $(this).children(":selected").data('auth');
  if (auth == 'need-purchase-auth') {
    $("#authorized_to_purchase").show();
  } else {
    $("#authorized_to_purchase").hide();
  }
});
```

Basically, we put an event listener on the select box to fire when you selected a different option. Then, we have to find which option was selected by checking which option has the :selected attribute. Then, we use the attr() method to get the data-auth attribute value. To finish up, you just have to check if the data-auth value is equal to what you are looking for. If so, show the checkbox. If not, hide it. Please let me know if you need further explanation on my code.

Comment: to get `data-auth` attribute you can use instead of `attr` just `data` and pass only `auth` like this `.data('auth')`. Documentation here https://api.jquery.com/data/ . And also instead of `css("display", "block")` use `show()`, instead of `css("display", "none")` - `hide()` https://api.jquery.com/show/ & https://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: You're totally right. Using show(), hide(), data() makes the code way cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//bind the event handler in your script, not inline
$( '#job_title' ).on( 'change', function () {
    if ( $( this ).find( 'option:checked' ).data( 'auth' ) === 'need-purchase-auth' ) {
        //do stuff
        console.log('weee');
    }
} );
```

Comment: He's not looking for the value but a data attribute of the selected option.

Comment: Use the `:selected` selector instead of `:checked` as the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) advice. > To retrieve only the selected options of select elements, use the :selected selector.

Comment: "Because :selected is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :selected cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :selected to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":selected"). " https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: I made some perf tests and you right. Here the results (based on a loop executed 1000 times). `option:selected` -> **108.94 ms**... `option:checked` -> **9.335000000000036 ms**... `filter(':selected')` -> **37.235000000000014 ms**... `filter(':checked')` -> **37.745000000000005 ms**... `document.getElementById().options[select.selectedIndex]` -> **0.6849999999999454 ms**. I'm done with `:selected`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the inline event handler and do it this way:

```js
$('#job_title').change(function showAuthBox(val) {
  if ($('option:selected', this).data('auth') == "need-purchase-auth") {
    $('#authorized_to_purchase_box').css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $('#authorized_to_purchase_box').css("display", "none");
  }
})
```

```css
#authorized_to_purchase_box {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="job_title" id="job_title">
  <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
  <option id="Superintendent" value="Superintendent">Superintendent</option>
  <option id="Assistant-Superintendent" value="Assistant Superintendent">Assistant Superintendent</option>
  <option id="Principal" value="Principal">Principal</option>
  <option id="Vice-Principal" value="Vice Principal">Vice Principal</option>
  <option id="Counselor" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Counselor">Counselor</option>
  <option id="Testing-Coordinator" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Testing Coordinator">Testing Coordinator</option>
  <option id="Curriculum-Director" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Curriculum Director">Curriculum Director</option>
  <option id="Administrator" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
  <option id="Teacher" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
  <option id="Parent" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Parent">Parent</option>
  <option id="Student" data-auth="need-purchase-auth" value="Student">Student</option>
</select>
<div id="authorized_to_purchase_box">
authorized_to_purchase_box
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen on *#job_title*'s change. Then check to see if the selected option is of "need-purchase-auth" data-auth. So you'd better change your funcion's body to this:

```
$('select#job_title').on("change", function () {
  var dataAuthVal = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-auth');
  if ('need-purchase-auth' == dataAuthVal) 
    $('#authorized_to_purchase_box').css("display", "block");
  else
    $('#authorized_to_purchase_box').css("display", "none");
```